# Angular and CodeIgniter Validation Library

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, validation, angularjs

I'm trying to us CodeIgniter's validation library on json data posted from Angularjs. The problem is when I go to set the validation rule the json object is not recognized as a post value by Codeigniter. Anybody know how to set a Codeigniter validation rule for a json object?

```
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    //die($data->name); = "Bob"
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($data->name, 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
       if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { 
          $this->output->set_output(validation_errors()); 
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Angular sends the data by POST, they should be available. Try `var_dump($_POST)` to see if there's anything in there (maybe it's malformed?).

If not, you can try this "hack":

```
 $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

before your validation.

So, do something like:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$this->form_validation->set_rules($data->name, 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
if(!$this->form_validation->run()) { 
   $this->output->set_output(validation_errors()); 
}
```

Comment: Open a webmasters tool (in chrome) or firebug (in firefox) and take a look at what is being send over to the sever.